# Iterating Fields in shapefile and exporting after interpolation geoprocessing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, interpolation

I have two shapefiles to be used for interpolating data.

The first is a survey point with the following attributes:

[image: Points]

The second is a boundary file (Polygon) with the corresponding descriptions as an attribute for the join:

[image: Boundary]

Now I need to interpolate the data using a IDW interpolation looping through the point shapefile to interpolate each attribute field.

Where it gets tricky is that the point needs to be interpolated according to the extent that they lie in. For example below. The IDW interpolation has to only use the selected points and use the extent of the boundary (Selected).

[image: Boundary & Points]

Now I have built a model to do this if I split all the point to the corresponding boundary  and split the boundaries which works but this is a tedious task and im sure there is a easier way.

Here is the current model:

[image: Model]

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following, if you have ArcMap 10.5 or higher.

1. Run spatial join of polygons to points, so the new point layer has polygon ID's
2. Run the [split by attribute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split-by-attributes.htm#) tool on new point layer splitting by polygon ID, fire that all into a single geodatabase.
3. Use iterate Featureclass and wire that up to you IDW tool and subsequent downstream processing.

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer. This does work but the iteration runs over and over when nested into model two.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 are essentially a one time run, preparing your inputs for the model. The result of steps 1 & 2 is a file geodatabase with as many point featureclasses as you have polygons.  Step  3 would be your main model starting with the iterator pulling out featureclasses of points  to feed into you IDW tool.